# Unable to publish in windows azure

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-web-roles

I have followed these steps:

- first download the publishsettings file
- then import it.

But import gives me error like
`There is an error in XML Document (0 0)` and after which next time even I reinstalled everything. 
This error is continuously coming without giving me option to choose other publishsetting file.

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio? The Node.js PowerShell tools? Something else? How are you downloading the .publishsettings file? What browser are you using? What OS? Have you opened it up to see if it's valid XML?

Answer (score 0):

Open Solution Explorer, open the project and under that open the Properties folder. In there you'll see the publishprofile files. Delete these. Go to the portal, download new publishsetting files and import these again.

[image]